# MySql Convert_tz()

Tags: mysql

The mysql function Convert_tz() is returning null vale. I populated the time zone tables and restarted mysql service multiple times. But the function is still returning null value.

Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks,
Gupta.

Comment: Show us the query you tried.

Comment: "This function returns NULL if the arguments are invalid." try to take a look at the argument, or include it in your post. It can help a lot.

Comment: The function that i'm using is select CONVERT_TZ(UTC_DATE(),'UTC','CST');

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the timezone table is not initialized. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html for more information on how to define it.

If you can't define the timezones, you can use `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(UTC_DATE(),'+0:00','-7:00');`

Comment: My Timezone tables are initialized. After initialization I restarted my sql service also. But still getting the issue.